# Functions which have for loop dependence

Tags: python, function, for-loop, recursion

Suppose I have the following:

```
def f(t):   
    return a*t

def g(t):  
    a=5  
    b=4  
    for u in range(t):  
        a=a+u  
        b=f(t)+b  
    return b
```

At each step, will the f(t) updating b in the 'for' loop have in its definition the updated a, or will it perpetually be 5?

Comment: As it is written now `a` is unknown in function `f`.

Comment: It is currently an error, if you move `def f(t)` inside of `def g()` then you will create a closure on `g()` and it would get the updated `a` (but you wouldn't need to pass in `t` either.

Answer (score 2):

for `f(t)` to have updated value of `a` in its defination, it should be passed as an argument to that function.
if you require that for every value of `t` `f(t)` has an updated `a` the do something like:

```
def f(t,a):
     return a*t
```

also in your defination of `f(t)` `a` is **undefined**. 
Then in `g(t)` modify `f(t)` to `f(t,a)`.

```
def g(t):  
    a=5  
    b=4  
    for u in range(t):  
        a=a+u  
        b=f(t,a)+b  
    return b
```